# What is the proper way to start session in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying with `wp_set_auth_cookie()`, but `$_SESSION` is always empty. What is the proper way to start a session and access the global array `$_SESSION` in WordPress?

Comment: [session_start](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php)

Comment: `session_start();` on every first line of `php` file where you need to use `$_SESSION`

Comment: I've tried to set session_start() in my header file but $_SESSION is still empty

Comment: read this for prefer to use session https://www.ironistic.com/using-php-sessions-in-wordpress/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use this code in `function.php`

```
add_action('init', 'start_session_wp', 1);
function start_session_wp() 
{
  if(!session_id())
  {
    session_start();
  }
}
```

Comment: setting in `init` will through warnings for wp-admin, session already start. so keep your session independent, start and use where it is needed.

Answer (score 2):

If done correctly your functions.php file should now look like this at the top.

```
add_action('init', 'start_session', 1);

function start_session() {
    if(!session_id()) {
        session_start();
    }

    add_action('wp_logout', 'end_session');
    add_action('wp_login', 'end_session');
    add_action('end_session_action', 'end_session');

    function end_session() {
        session_destroy ();
    }
}
```

You can now add data to the global `$_SESSION` variable that will be accessible at any point within the application during a user session by accessing the `$_SESSION` variable. The variable is an array; below is an example of adding data to the session array.

```
$foo = 'Foo Data';
$_SESSION['foo'] = $foo;
```

Answer (score 0):

This results in the following code to start and destroy the session:

```
add_action('init', 'myStartSession', 1);
add_action('wp_logout', 'myEndSession');
add_action('wp_login', 'myEndSession');

function myStartSession() {
    if(!session_id()) {
        session_start();
    }
}

function myEndSession() {
    session_destroy ();
}
```

**To save some data into the session**

```
$_SESSION['myKey'] = "Some data I need later";
And to get that data out at a later time

if(isset($_SESSION['myKey'])) {
    $value = $_SESSION['myKey'];
} else {
    $value = '';
}
```